# A square board of size n*n

Tags: function-construction, number-theory, averages

I would like to Randomly generate n^2 natural numbers in an interval from 1 to n. Then consider placing each number on the cell with the same number (you can imagine the board numbered naturally, row by row, from 1 to n). At the end, some cells might be empty. I would like to count the empty cells, let's say this number is empty. Now, you want to calculate n^2/empty which will be called result.
Then Write a function boiler[] that takes as argument the square of natural number larger or equal than 64 and m the number of iterations. The function returns the average of result obtained from m repetitions of the above procedure.This is what I have so far

```
boiler[n_] := {
  bo = DeleteDuplicates[Select[(RandomInteger[{1, n}, n])^2, # < n &]];
  Length[Select[Range[{1, n}], # != bo] &]}
```

Comment: Please share Mathematica code for what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: I updates my question with some code I tried but can't seem to complete

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you wish to place random numbers ranging from 1 to n in an n x n two-dimension array, based on the value of each random number.  How do you determine the two indices of an array cell from a single random number?

Comment: It is random numbers generated from 1 to n but n is squared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand this correctly. But here is my understanding.

We first define a function: "getresult" with an input of "n". First we create n^2 random numbers. Then we calculate the indices where these numbers would be placed and mark this places by an "1". Then we count the non-marked places what gives "empty". Finally we return n^2/ empty if empty != 0. Otherwiese we write a message and return 0.

As a lst step we define "boiler", that takes n and m= number of repetitions as input. The out put is the mean result.

```
getresult[n_] := Module[{d, board, empty, indices, i},
   d = RandomInteger[{1, n}, n^2];
   indices = Partition[d, n] + Range[0, n - 1] n // Flatten;
   board = ConstantArray[0, n^2];
   board[[indices]] = 1;
   empty = Count[board, 0];
   If[empty == 0, Print["empty is zero"]; 0, n^2/empty // N]
   ];
boiler[n_, m_] := Total[Table[getresult[n], m]]/m
```

We may test this by:

```
boiler[64^2, 10]

(* 2.71825 *)
```